# PHP - How can I join value in 2 array

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays like this:

```
$array1 = array('1','2','3','4','5','6');
$array2 = array('a','b','c','d','e','f');
```

I want to create a text file, which will be display line by line with "\n" as following. How to do this?

```
1a

2b

3c

4d

5e

6f
```

Comment: `foreach(){}` is a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using array_map. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

```
$array1 = [1, 2];
$array2 = ['a', 'b'];

$newArray = array_map(function ($value1, $value2) {
    return "$value1$value2";
}, $array1, $array2);

print_r($newArray);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1a
    [1] => 2b
)
```

And to save to file:

```
file_put_contents('myfile.txt', join("\n", $newArray));
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple foreach will do that

```
foreach( $array1 as $idx => $a1 )
    echo $a1 . $array2[$idx] . PHP_EOL;
    // if you really want the extra blank line then
    //echo $a1 . $array2[$idx] . PHP_EOL. PHP_EOL;
}
```

> But the 2 arrays must always have the same number of occurances or you will get errors